# C# save confirmation message while leaving form

Tags: c#, winforms

What is the best way to show a save confirmation message while leaving (not closing - set focus to another form) a none modal form?

The user has the options of

- yes (save changes and set focus to targetform)
- no  (rollback and set focus to target form)
- cancel (stay in active form - cancel setting focus to target form)

I can't find a solution to prevent setting focus to another form. Similar to closing event, where I can use FormClosingEventArgs.Cancel property.

To use a modal form is not acceptable in my case.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which ways have you found or tried? Or what didn't work out about the solution you attempted to use at first?

Comment: The translation of @O.R.Mapper 's comment is "Have your read about some of the conventions used in Stack Overflow?" :)

Comment: The Main problem: I can't find a solution to prevent setting focus to another form.

Comment: Show the form like `myForm.ShowDialog();` this will prevent it being closed...

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can use the `Deactivated` event to detect when the form loses focus. Then, if the user wants to stay in the form that lost focus, you can call the `BringToFront` method to set the form active again.

You can not prevent the user from activating another form, but you can try (using the above) to change activation back to the current form.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works. One Problem still remains if I show a messagebox in Deactivated Event. Therefore MessageBox receives focus. After confirm dialog, focus is set back to active form not to the origin target form. I think I have to use IWinOwner parameter in MessageBox.Show() methode, but I don't know how to get the target form.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do it would be to override the OnLostFocus event. Here's the code:

```
protected override void OnLostFocus(EventArgs e) { 
    base.OnLostFocus(e); 
    this.Focus(); 
}
```